MobaXterm: Cannot reach ipv6 only host on VNC
I have a RaspberryPi running VNC server with native IPv6, but while trying to connect to the host using MobaXterm, I am facing the following error:
Sorry, connection to VNC server failed. 
Cannot reach host  on port 5900.
while the same connects when I try from RealVNC Client.
Does MobaXterm does support connecting to VNC hosts on native IPv6? 
I have both host and client on a Tailscale network. MobaXterm works fine when I connect to the host with its tailscale private IP.
